# Tkinter Python error: _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type StringVar cannot be converted

Tags: python, tkinter

I have lengthy code so I just copied what I think is affected. I am making a GUI shop from tkinter in Python. I have an error when I execute the code Error is:

```
"user.py", line 1826, in Register_Employee
    cur.execute(sql_command, values)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 257, in execute
    prepared = self._cnx.prepare_for_mysql(params)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 645, in prepare_for_mysql
    result = self._cmysql.convert_to_mysql(*params)
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type StringVar cannot be converted"
```

Would you know what is this error about? Do you need additional information or code?
Thank you

```
e_f_name = StringVar()
e_m_name = StringVar()
e_l_name = StringVar()
e_gender = StringVar()
e_month = StringVar()
e_position = StringVar()
e_address = StringVar()
e_city = StringVar()
e_zip = IntVar()
e_country = StringVar()
e_email = StringVar()
eusername = StringVar()
epass = StringVar()



my_cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee("
                "emp_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
                "first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
                "middle_initial VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
                "last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
                "gender VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,"
                "birth_date DATE NOT NULL,"
                "position VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,"
                "contact_number VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,"
                "address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
                "city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
                "region VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
                "zip_code INT NOT NULL,"
                "country VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
                "email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
                "username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,"
                "password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL)")

sql_command = "INSERT INTO employee (first_name, middle_initial, last_name, gender, birth_date, position, contact_number, address, city, region, zip_code, country, email, username, password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
values = (e_f_name, e_m_name, e_l_name, e_gender,  e_month, e_position,  e_mobile, e_address, e_city, e_region, e_zip, e_country, e_email, eusername, epass)
cur.execute(sql_command, values)
```

Comment: you need to manually convert the values from all `StringVar` variable to type `str`

Comment: You can use `<tkinter.StringVar object>.get()` to get the value of the `StringVar`. Also it doesn't look like your `StringVar`s are attached to anything so they will always return `""`. Are they attached to entries?

Comment: Thank you xcodz and TheLizzard. Got an additional question. In my tkinter, there is a combobox for day, month, and year. How can I combine them so that it can reflect in mySQL since the data type for this is DATE? I use concetenate and also datetime. Thank you